# Color a cell in column B if column's A cell in that row is the same as B's header

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-docs, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a set of columns like this in a Google Spreadsheet:

```
A1 B1
A2 B2
A3 B3
A4 B4
AX BX
```

And I want to change the color of any BN cell in case AN is the same as B1.

I tried `=IF(A2=B1)` then a range of `B2:B100`, but it doesn't work...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I want to change the color of any BN cell in case AN is the same
>   as B1.

Use:

`=A2=B$1`

applied to B2:B100.